# I want to be an Appetize.io(or Browserstack) in China. Should I learn about open source projects or knowledge?

Tags: debugging, web, mobile, remote-debugging, simulator

[Appetize.io](https://appetize.io/demo?device=iphone6s&scale=75&orientation=portrait&osVersion=11.4) or [Browserstack.com](https://www.browserstack.com/) can't access it normally in China, so I want to implement a tool myself. Like Appetize (or Browserstack), I can use my different versions of mobile devices to debug my webpage online, but I don't know where to start. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Network Activity tab of Chrome Dev Tools while you are on the demo page for Appetize.io. You will see a bunch of JPEG images being streamed to the browser as you interact with the device "screen" on the browser. Most likely an emulator/simulator is fired up in the backend and screenshots are taken at regular intervals and streamed to the browser.

That would be a good start. The next thing to look at would be how to capture input (typing and screen taps) on the browser and then "execute" those type/taps on the emulator in the backend.